# Error: You are not allowed to remove the Unity splash screen from your game

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to run my Unity game in Xcode.
When 'Device SDK' is configured in the Unity iOS player setting, everything is fine. But when I switch to 'Simulator SDK' (to use the iOS simulator), the following error occurs in Xcode on startup of my game:

**You are using Unity iPhone Basic. You are not allowed to remove the Unity splash screen from your game.**

Due to this error the game crashes on startup. I didn't change anything regarding the splash screen in my Unity player settings. So what could be the cause of this problem?
I found some results on Google regarding this error, but none seems to help...

PS: I'm using Unity 4.6.3 and Xcode 6.1.1
Those should be the latest versions available.

Comment: What are the devices and simulators you're attempting to test with?

Comment: It works with none of the simulators (iPhone, iPad...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i found a solusion bellow:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/you-are-not-allowed-to-remove-the-unity-splash-screen-from-your-game.299906/

For anyone else experiencing this issue:

1. Make a build.
2. In xCode - select Unity-iPhone target from your Targets list and select the Info tab.
3. Delete the key **UILaunchStoryboardName~iphone** from the Custom iOS Target Properties.
4. Try again, it should work fine.

Comment: This is so random, worked for me last week and doesn't work today. Hope this is fixed in the new unity, did not upgrade yet. Happened on `Unity 4.6.3f1`

Comment: yep I confirm that, I moved to Unity 5 yesterday and did not have the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

On Unity 4.6.3f1 I have the same issue.
It works fine if I delete the key UILaunchStoryboardName~iphone to run the game as suggested.

Choosing to append or replace does not make any difference for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same setup and problem - i resolved it by rolling back Unity to previous version (i didn't delete it). 4.6.0 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a new error introduced in unity v4.6.1 and is reproducible in v-4.6.3

While creating the build you should not append but do a replace.
Maybe this would fix the issue instead of rolling back to a previous version.