# Xcode 8 : Unity 4.6.9 - You are not allowed to remove the Unity splash screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode8

When I run game with Xcode 8, I see unity splash screen then it crashes. Code worked perfect in Xcode 7, but same code crashing in Xcode 8 with below message.

> You are using Unity iPhone Basic. You are not allowed to remove the
>   Unity splash screen from your game

Unity version : 4.6.9

How to fix it for Xcode 8 ?

Already tried This but not fixed in Xcode 8 : [Error: You are not allowed to remove the Unity splash screen from your game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658272/error-you-are-not-allowed-to-remove-the-unity-splash-screen-from-your-game)

[image]

**Some More Observation:**
 Compress png in Xcode 8 compresses splash screen more than Xcode 7. So this is the route cause. Waiting for Unity team to fix issue with splash screen comparision methods.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658272/error-you-are-not-allowed-to-remove-the-unity-splash-screen-from-your-game

Comment: @Maulik, I already tried that for iOS9 then it worked in iOS9, but now even with that fix its crashing in iOS 10 .

Comment: Can you also please fix the remote notification error ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009006/parse-warning-from-didreceiveremotenotificationfetchcompletionhandler and try ?

Comment: Also your question fits here : http://answers.unity3d.com/ may be you are using old Unity SDK and need to update to support Xcode 8 !

Comment: @Maulik, yes only in Xcode 8 crash comes...in Xcode 7 works. I cant update unity3d as it gives lots of error in Unity 5. So is there any fix for Unity 4.6.9 to support Xcode 8 ?

Comment: well I am not sure about Unity 3D but you can search for a patch if any available.

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @NoorAli Apple fixed this problem in Xcode 8.1

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor good to hear that but I purchased Unity Plus license and all worked well. :)

Comment: @NoorAli How much it cost for Unity Plus license ? One time payment or montly payment ?

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor There was a promotion in november 25% off. Original it costs 35$ per month and its a subscription for 1 year.

https://store.unity.com/products/unity-plus

Comment: @NoorAli so you paid 35$ for 1 year Or 35$ per month ?

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor before asking that question. Did you click the link I gave?

Comment: yes, it says 35/month...really costly

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor yes exactly. There was a promotion a few months ago. You can get monthly subscription for $26. Now It's off. They might turn that on. Subscribe on unity website for latest upates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good News. Apple fixed this problem in Xcode 8.1

Apple reverted their changes related to compress PNG and this fixed splash screen comparison problem in Unity exported code.